# While loop hangs

Tags: python, while-loop

This is my code. I am calling a variable "data_entry" in while loop (instead of asking a question). I want to check if this data_entry variable is within a given range. The data_entry variable is converted to an integer by seeking user input

```
data_entry = int(user_captured_entry)

while True:
   data_entry
   if 0 <= data_entry <= 100:
      break
   print('Out of range. Please try again')
```

Comment: `data_entry` isn't between 0..100

Comment: What exactly is not working as expected? as @ozgur sais, you will have an infinite loop if data_entry is not betweeen 0..100. Is this what you mean by "hanging"?

Comment: There might be a misconception that the line `data_entry` in the loop does something. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop. If `data_entry` is less than 0 or greater than 100 the loop will iterate forever, without giving the user the opportunity to update their number. I think you need to include `data_entry = int(user_captured_entry)` inside the loop, as at the moment the user will not be repeatedly polled for a new value.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed that. My code should have been 
>= 0 and =<1000. Pardon me - I am new to Python

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture the user's input **inside** the while loop to try again and again until a valid input is captured:

```
while True:
   # take input from user here
   user_captured_entry = # capture input
   data_entry = int(user_captured_entry)
   if 0 <= data_entry <= 100:
      # input OK - leave while loop
      break
   print('Out of range. Please try again')
```

Otherwise an invalid end up will leave you with an infinite while loop that checks the same (invalid) input again and again.

Comment: I prefer to use the question outside the loop and want to store the response from the user as a variable and then use the variable elsewhere.

Comment: If you're asking once that's ok. But I must ask what the loop is for in the first place...

Comment: The loop is just to check whether the data (user input) captured in the variable is within the given range =>10 and =<100

Comment: Why not use an `if` statement?

Comment: Appreciate you taking time Reut but I prefer to somehow achieve this via the "while" loop

Comment: @TRex The question is why are you looping at all? You only do one check, after which there's no re-prompt for user data, so your loop EITHER exits on the first run, OR runs forever.

Comment: Yeh you really shouldn't be looping here if that's your requirement. It's not a preference thing.